# Rails 3.1rc4 and 404 not found when accessing assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to port my rails 3.0.7 project to rails 3.1

I have Phusion Passenger running on nginx + rvm.

There is config.assets.enabled = true in my application.rb file.

I created empty rails 3.1 project and copied my app directory, routes.rb and application.rb files over it. I moved everything from public to app/assets (app/assets/stylesheets etc).
When I'm trying to access assets (application.css/application.js), I'm getting 404 not found error, but I can see them in app/assets/stylesheets/application.css and app/assets/javascripts/application.js.

Help me please.

UPD: Thanks to Devin M for the idea, I removed css,js,gif,png and jpg extensions from nginx.conf ("serve static files directly") and everything started to work.

Comment: How are you trying to access these files?

Comment: What do your hosts look like? nginx.conf?

Comment: @Devin M, thanks for the idea, now it works :) P.S. I'll accept your answer if you write it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually this is a problem with the nginx config not set up to serve things correctly. Double check your config files.

Comment: Could you please explain to which problem you are referring to? The solution provided by zachaysan worked for me.

Comment: If you don't set up Nginx right you can get 404's. Basically my answer means to look over those.

Answer (score 4):

I came to this question with a similar problem (everything was giving a 404) I found that Rails 3.1.0.rc4 has a problem with gem 'sprockets'

In your Gemfile set:

```
gem 'sprockets', '= 2.0.0.beta.10'
```

Note: you may have to manually override your Gemfile.lock before you `bundle install`

Comment: By manually override I mean change any instance of 2.0.0.beta.11 to beta.10 for sprockets

Comment: This may not be the right answer for the original question, but it fixed a problem I was having.  Thanks!

Comment: anyone got a link to the github issue for this? I want to track it so I can know when it I can drop the gemfile entry

Comment: Mike, I'm surprised that you are still having this problem. I reported it in the IRC channel while they were talking about the latest candidate. Unfortunately I've been too busy with node work to watch what has been happening in Rails right now though.

Comment: Same problem, 404 on every assets with rails 3.1.0.rc1.